# What's the "editing finished" signal of a QTableView item?

Tags: qt4, qtableview

I want to know when user has finished editing a QTableView item, so I checked all the available signals, but I only found ones that will emit before the edit.

So, what should I do now?

Running Qt 4.8.4

Answer (score 9):

Since your QTableView will have attached a model, connect to its signals,

eg 
[void QStandardItemModel::itemChanged ( QStandardItem * item ) [signal]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemChanged)

or, more generally:

[void QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged ( const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged)

You can, also, connect to the [selection model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) signals.
Usually, when you finish editing an item, focus changes to next, so selectionmodel will fire 
[currentChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentChanged) but this hasnt to be general.

Answer (score 9):

True signal about finished editing you can find only in `QAbstractItemDelegate`. It is [`closeEditor()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#closeEditor) signal. All another signals from models will not work if user does not change anything in cell, but delegate is closed everytime when editing is finished. As doc said:

> This signal is emitted when the user has finished editing an item
>   using the specified editor.
>
> The hint provides a way for the delegate to influence how the model
>   and view behave after editing is completed. It indicates to these
>   components what action should be performed next to provide a
>   comfortable editing experience for the user. For example, if
>   EditNextItem is specified, the view should use a delegate to open an
>   editor on the next item in the model.

Usage:

```
connect(ui->tableView->itemDelegate(),SIGNAL(closeEditor(QWidget*,QAbstractItemDelegate::EndEditHint)),SLOT(someSlot()));
```